# How does the xorg server display stuff without an api like opengl

Tags: opengl, xorg

How does the xorg server render stuff without an api like opengl? How does it access the gpu without an api? How does it draw to the screen(for example XDrawRectangle in xlib) without an api?

Comment: xorg server talks to the driver; the driver implements opengl along with other apis (like accessing the framebuffer or blitting images). These answers may help you (even though some of them talk about Windows): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10926533/277176) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591338/277176) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40544917/277176)

Comment: ...what makes you think (modern) Xorg versions [*don't* use OpenGL](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Glamor/)?